# How to replicate animated shader material from Maya in Unity without shader graphs?

Tags: unity, shaders

I am new to shaders and experimenting with the free Unity shader forge plugin. Due to project limitations I am using Unity 2019.4 and cannot use Unity's shadergraph =(

[image: Animated material example]

[I found this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FM-XUP_4WAE), which exactly creates the effect that I am looking for. Unfortunately, it is done in Maya and I am quite lost how to replicate this effect, since I don't know how to integrate that noise. My shader works right to the point of the scrolling grid.

[image: Example shader graph]

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just a known name for this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the keyword here is *noise*. The person from the video is distorting the UVs from the mesh through a *noise field*. In your case, what you need is a **noise node**. I've never used Shader Forge before, but it should have a *gradient noise* or *noise* node.

This node should be mixed along the UVs from your mesh using an *Add node*, something like this:

[image]

The above example was done in Shader Graph, but should still work in Shader Forge.
The premise is that the texture will follow the noise creating a distortion effect. This is a very common setup for creating caustics or water distortion shaders, of which there are many tutorials on the internet.